# How to download sdk?

Tags: android, sdk, deveco-studio

I can't find the setting option in configure. How to download sdk? After setting up the environment variable how will I know that everything is done?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try creating a new project it should download the latest SDK.. then access SDK Manager through Android studio

Comment: you can try to use brew ```brew install android-platform-tools```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.